# Should I use chair armrest or not?

Tags: posture

I am planning to remove the armrest of my chair because of it I cannot increase the height of my chair as it hit's the table.

Is it really effective to use chair armrest?

Comment: Both your question and premise are confusing, I’m having a hard time understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I often ask my clients to *avoid* the armrests.

Invariably, people end up with their arms like this for 8+ hours a day:

[image: armrests abduction]

Often leading to leaning on the elbows, which can push the top of the shoulder upwards, recreating impingement. Notice her right shoulder pushing into her collarbone area,

[image: humeral glide]

Plus, abduction i.e. raising your arms out to the side, is when many with a shoulder history will have problems.

[image: shoulder abduction]

In other words, holding the shoulder in abduction all day isn't ideal when abduction is the source of many people's shoulder pain:

[image: abduction arm rests shoulders]

I've had people whose arms (deltoids) become stiff into this position to the point they stand like this,

[image: shoulder abduction standing]

Now they're holding their arms in that position while typing and standing aka basically all day. Not a recipe for the shoulders feeling good longterm.

Images taken from: [Why typing annoys your neck, shoulders, elbows and wrists, and what to do about it](https://b-reddy.org/why-typing-annoys-your-neck-shoulders-elbows-and-wrists-and-what-to-do-about-it/)